# Full post content is displayed even when <!--moretag--> is added to Post WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have created a WordPress theme. For the home-page I am using front-page.php.

On the home page, I have a section where I am displaying posts from a single category, which has two posts, both containing the 'more' tag.

The issue I am facing is that the full post content is displayed.

Below is the code from front-page.php:

```
<?php
    $catquery = new WP_Query( 'cat=3&posts_per_page=2' );
    while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post();
    ?>
        <p class="contentText">
        <?php the_content( $more_link_text, $stripteaser ); ?>
        </p>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Can you post some of the HTML surrounding the 'more' tag?  Wordpress is pretty specific about how it processes that tag.

Comment: Here is the output: <p><img class="pull-left contentImgRight" src="" alt="event1"> event 2 Duis nec nisl accumsan ligula blandit porta sit amet sed elit.&nbsp;In vel diam auguett. Maecenas pulvinar rhoncus eros, et volutpat mi ivan.<span id="more-84"></span></p>

<p>after read more link Duis nec nisl accumsan ligula blandit porta sit amet sed elit.&nbsp;In vel diam auguett. Maecenas pulvinar rhoncus eros, et volutpat mi .</p>

Comment: Can you post the HTML from the post itself?  From Wordpress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The more tag is ignored in templates where just one post is displayed. Over-ride the default `$more` global variable inside The Loop.

```
<?php if ($catquery->have_posts()) : while ($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post(); ?>
<?php global $more; $more = 0; ?>
// content
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Comment: Currently this category has two post and I am displaying two posts on the page. I tried your code and it when into a indefinite loop. I just took the <?php global $more; $more = 0; ?> and add to my code and it works. Thanks a lot for your help..

Comment: You are displaying two posts on the page with a custom query, but it is inside front-page.php that is a single page template, and more tag does not work in "Pages". [Here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More#How_to_use_Read_More_in_Pages) is more info about.